# Why is this user "Admin" created in all databases?

Tags: sql-server, users

When I create database in SQL server Management Studio, user with name "admin" is also created for all databases:

[image]

Why this user is created? And how I can change this behavior?

Comment: Looks like I have found the reason, this user exists in System Databases=> Model. That is why it was created for all new databases.

Comment: Add your own comment as a response so the question doesn't linger 'unanswered'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I have found the reason, this user exists in System Databases=> Model. That is why it was created for all new databases.

Comment: I was going to say that it was probably in the Model database.  Good job figuring it out.